# Возможно ли в react получить нормальнкю ошибку из laravel?

Tags: laravel, reactjs

У меня при дубликате записей допусти login в php высвечивается нормально ошибка а вот при получение его в axios там указывается ошибка как `Error: Request failed with status code 500.`
Или для этих задач между общением с бэкендом служит node js?

Comment: покажите пример "нормальной ошибки", для непосвящённых. добавьте переносы строк. используйте обратные кавычки для выделения ошибок https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code-spans.

Comment: В контроллере вместо throw new Exception возвращайте Json ответ с ошибкой, а в реакте просто парсим Json и выводим. А в случае если ошибки нет - возвращаем просто статус 200

Comment: НУ как я понял там разные языки и поэтому такие не стыковки с ошибками. Я предполагаю

Comment: можно возвращать json как описали выше, но я думаю, что вы просто не обрабатываете reject - состояние промиса, именно там вы можете получить ошибку и обработать её